# RxJS Observable subscription, why if we do not unsubscribe it causes memory leak?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

There is a lot about this subject already, I went through a lot of stack but could not find a clear answer.

I am wondering why a `Subscription` is still active when it does not exist anymore in the scope, to illustrate :

```
Observable myData$ = Observable<Data>; // being set above

someFn(): void => {
  let subscription = myData$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}

someFn();

//code continue
```

I am already aware that it causes memory leak etc. What I want to understand is how does it happen ?

From the official documentation :

> *With observable.subscribe, the given Observer is not registered as a listener in the Observable. The Observable does not even maintain a list of attached Observers.*

In my understanding the Subscription above should be garbage collected and so not active anymore ? How does the memory leak occurs ?

Comment: It still very much is active and therefore will continue to exist until it is unsubscribed. You can test this by setting up subscriptions in a `ngOnInit` and do some route changes - you'll end up with more and more subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends on `myData$` observable.

If it automatically completes, then you should not worry about unsubscribing from it.

But if it doesn't, then here is why I think you should manually unsubscribe.

Suppose you have a **shared** service, `SharedService`, which has a private `BehaviorSubject` and exposes it with the `asObservable()` method.

```js
class SharedService {
  private userSbj = new BehaviorSubject({});

  user$ = this.userSbj.asObservable();
}
```

Let's see what happens when `ComponentA` subscribes to `user$` and consumes it:

```js
class ComponentA {
  constructor (private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit () {
    this.userAge$ = this.sharedService.user$.pipe(pluck('

    this.subscription = this.userAge$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

`userAge$` comes from `user$`. But remember that `user$` is just `BehaviorSubject.asObservable()`. What this means is that when a new subscriber is registered, it will be added to the **subscribers list** maintained by the `BehaviorSubject`.

If you are not manually unsubscribing, then that subscriber will still be part of that , even though the component might be destroyed. That **subscribers list** still keeps a reference to that subscriber. But, if you do unsubscribe, say in `ngOnDestroy`:

```js
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Then, that subscriber will be **removed** from that subscribers list, so, since the subscriber is no longer referenced from any other place, you will not have any memory leaks.

---

[This](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts#L24-L30) is what happens when a `BehaviorSubject` is being subscribed to:

```js
_subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<T>): Subscription {
  const subscription = super._subscribe(subscriber);
  if (subscription && !(<SubscriptionLike>subscription).closed) {
    subscriber.next(this._value);
  }
  return subscription;
}
```

In `super._subscribe(subscriber)`, `super` refers to `Subject`, because `BehaviorSubject` extends `Subject`:

[`Subject._subscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/d13eb3016a60f6aca862c64f6cfb1953b4776dca/src/internal/Subject.ts#L118-L119):

```js
// adding to the subscribers(observers) list
this.observers.push(subscriber);
return new SubjectSubscription(this, subscriber);
```

[`SubjectSubscription`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/d13eb3016a60f6aca862c64f6cfb1953b4776dca/src/internal/SubjectSubscription.ts#L10) plays an important role here, since it's responsible for removing the subscriber from the subscribers list.